# How to check if a particular entry in a CheckedListBox is checked

Tags: c#

Sorry if the question is silly - I've never worked with this before. I did some research but none gave satisfying solution. What I want is only to see if a particular entry is checked, I don't care about other entries in the `CheckedListBox` (at least for now). So is there an easier way like I can do `IsChecked` for a `CheckBox`?

Comment: There is CheckedItems and CheckedIndices which return the collection of checked items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns a boolean value representing whether the item is checked or not.

```
CheckedListBox.GetItemChecked(index)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemchecked(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is index just the TabIndex when defining the entry？

Comment: index would be the index of the item in the Check List Box.  If you just want to get a collection of the checked items, you can get that by saying `CheckListBox.CheckedItems` and going from there.

Comment: Ok, so is this index defined when I do `checkedListBox.Items.AddRange(...)`, the index into that?

Comment: It depends on if items already exist within that checkListBox.  If you look at Items, index is the location of the item you want within that collection.  If you have 5 items in your checkListBox and you add another, the index of that new item will be 5, since it is a 0-based index system.